# How can I debug Classic ASP in WebMatrix?

Tags: asp-classic, webmatrix

I'm working with Classic ASP web Application hosted in WebMatrix. Is there a way to debug a website hosted in WebMatrix ?

Comment: The way to debug classic ASP is to view the page through the browser (via the server) and if there is an error then the type of error and the filename and line where it occurs will be displayed.  Webmatrix uses IIS express, which is designed as a development server, so there should be no issues configuring "full" IIS to display error messages

Answer (score 3):

WebMatrix offers little (nothing) by way of debugging tools. You can `Response.Write` variables, rendering their value to the browser. This was the 'traditional' way to debug classic ASP in the absence of anything more advanced. But there is no way to attach to process or anything like that.